# How to create a stateful, queue like function in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Is there a way to create a JavaScript function that:

1. Takes a function as an argument which returns a promise
2. Returns after the previous call's returned

For example:

```
function resolveInOrder(fun: ()=>Promise<any>): Promise<void> {
   return fun().then(result => console.log(result));
}

resolveInOrder(()=>somePromise1);
resolveInOrder(()=>somePromise2);
resolveInOrder(()=>somePromise3);
```

Should result in (independently of how long it takes to resolve each promise):

```
somePromise1Result
somePromise2Result
somePromise3Result
```

Comment: Assuming we whip up a solution where we store the promises inside an array and wait until `Promise.all` resolves. What happens when you are trying to add 5 promises to the queue and you have done so uptil 3 and then all promises already in queue resolve before you get to the last one? Don't you need a trigger then? To start executing the promises in queue when you tell it to start?

Comment: You can chain these like `somePromise1.then(() => somePromise2).then(() => somePromise3)`, etc. Is there a reason that won't work?

Comment: @ExplosionPills These promises can't be chained like that because resolveInOrder() is called from external services multiple (unknown how many) times

Comment: @JanekCzarnota in that case, I think that you will have to call it recursively